# Python - Create Dictionary From Nested List and Dictionaries

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm trying to create a dictionary from values within dictionaries within lists. See the following example:

```
dict1={'x':1,'y':7}
dict2={'x':2,'y':8}
dict3={'x':3,'y':9}

list1=[dict1,dict2,dict3]
list2=[dict3]
list3=[dict2,dict3]

A=[list1,list2,list3]
```

How do I loop through the lists and dicts to create a new dict for {x:y}?

```
newdict={A[0][0]['x']:A[0][0]['y'] ,..., A[2][1]['x']:A[2][1]['y']}
```

I tried:

```
newdict={}
for i in A:
   newdict[i]={A[i][j]['x']:A[i][j]['y'] for j in A[i]}
```

But I got an error "list indices must be integers or slices, not list"

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the solution you have written which produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: So, to summarize... `A` is a list of lists, each list is a list of dictionaries, and each dictionary has the keys `x`, `y`, and `z`? Is that right? And the newly-created dictionary has entries where the key is the value of `x` and the value is the value of `y`?

Comment: Is anything done with the value of 'z'?

Comment: @itprorh66 sorry about that - edited to include code that can be reproduced. Can't include too much data as it is sensitive information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```py
foo_dict = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
inner_list = [foo_dict]
outer_list = [inner_list]

newdict = {d['x']: d['y'] for inner in outer_list for d in inner}
# => {1: 2}
```

Using your recently added example:

```py
all_xy = {d['x']: d['y'] for inner in A for d in inner}
# => {1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9}
```